# Facebook open graph "provided image doesn't have a supporte extension"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting this error trying to load an image on Facebook Open Graph for my website.

> Unsupported Image File Extension Provided og:image URL,
>   http://www.maikel.uk:3000/images/logos/logoSEO.jpg does not have a
>   supported extension.

[Facebook Developer screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3str.jpg)

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, I've checked all over the place but this doesn't seem to be a common error. The file extension is correct and the format too.

These are my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.maikel.uk" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Maikel.uk" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A Content Management System to empower self-directed learning." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.maikel.uk:3000/images/logos/logoSEO.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.maikel.uk/images/logos/logoSEO.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="272" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Maikel.uk logo" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="117025065673975" />
```

Comment: Why the weird port? Same image seems to be available via default port 80 as well, so what’s that good for? // You don’t need to specify a secure and a normal version of the same image, Facebook will place a copy on their own CDN anyways, so HTTP/HTTPS is not an issue.